# Method that checks if all edittexts are empty always return true

Tags: android

This may be something very simple that I have overlooked but I have this method here:

```
    public boolean isEdited(){

    for (int i = 0; i <= EDITTEXT_IDS.length; i++ ){
        EditText edittext = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(EDITTEXT_IDS[i]);
        if(isEmpty(edittext)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
    return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

Which as you can see runs through a list of edittext boxes by id here:

```
private static final int[] EDITTEXT_IDS = {
        R.id.entry_home,
        R.id.entry_away
};
```

The method isEdited only has issues if I use an array. If I do them individually it works fine. Like so:

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
    return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.entry_home);
isEmpty(editText);
```

It's probably something so minor.
I would really like the method to be like so:

```
public boolean isEdited(){

for ( id : EDITTEXT_IDS){
    EditText edittext = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(id);
    if(isEmpty(edittext)){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= EDITTEXT_IDS.length   THis should get you an index out of bounds error.  It ought to be <, not <=

Comment: return inside for doesn't behave as expected. So may be store it in hashmap etc and check if all true then return true else return false.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I don't know what a hashmap is nor have I ever used one.

Comment: Apart from the issue pointed out by @GabeSechan, are you sure you wanted `isEmpty(editText)` and not `!isEmpty(editText)` inside your `for` loop? Right now your method `isEdited` returns `true` if **any** `EditText` is empty. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: might I suggest using apache `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)` instead? There are some beautiful function in there, I consider it pretty essential personally.

Comment: Also if you really want to know what is going on, place a break point in your function and debug the thing :)

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you guys I have included these changes. However, it still continually returns the same bool.

Comment: @Bartek Lipinski see above ^^^^ (Can only tag one person)

Comment: @WIllJBD What do I need to import to use `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)`?

Comment: It seems like from the comments that at first glance this function should be working properly?

Comment: `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'` in your build.gradle

Comment: Thank you guys! I do not know if I am allowed to say this here but I have one more question that I need answered. I don't know if you can view the questions that I've asked or not. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change:

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
    return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

for this:

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText myeditText) {
    return myeditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("");
}
```

But i think it's a good idea check if your EditTexts are been finding on the array, maybe you misspelled some of the names on the Array declaration

Comment: Actually once you trim the white space from the string, the correct and readable way would be to use `.trim().isEmpty()` however I suggest StringUtils.isEmpty because it will null check the value for you, which may not be useful here, but in general can be.

Comment: @WIllJBD The method `getText()` never returns null, it return the value or an empty value, what may return null is the declaration of the editText, in this case, the `getText() ` will throw an exception. Best way for me is check if the EditText is not null before try to get the text. About the Library, may have something useful but i think is better try to resolve thing without add new dependencies, unless the implementation with the natives tools will require a lot of code, or result in some fails. in this, case, will just replace a EditText != null, so not worth the cost

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro the reference will never be null once looked up if looked up correctly in the appropriate place in a lifecycle, unless you are accessing in response to a non UI thread. I know that `getText()` does not return null, however for readability, consistency, and all else that is good programming, you should standardize such a call with something like `StringUtils.isEmpty(string)`, whether using apache or your own util method. this will hardly be the only place in a enterprise application where a string is being evaluated for empty, and to decouple you would watch out for a null.

Comment: @WIllJBD `findViewById()` for example may return null, it's a good idea check if the reference is not null (the Android Studio highlight a warning when you use that) , i agree the empty check may be decoupled and i don't say other way, i just say it's not needed to add an dependency for just check empty Strings.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro `findViewById()` will only return null if you don't know what you are doing. when you go to look up a view, you should know that it is already there. doing a null check on it is pointless. If it returns null, you messed up, and you shouldn't design in a way that you might ever expect a null. Unfortunately people do mess up, and build badly architected apps, cause they just don't understand the lifecycle, and how Android works.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is more of a "teach a man to fish" answer, but here it is

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

in that link it will show you how to place a break point in the code, and than step through your functions as they go. You will see all your variables and what they contain etc.

also to use apache StringUtils, or to add any dependency, yo just add a line to the dependencies of your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

also try this

```
// I assume this function is to return true when there has been input to all edit texts in the array
public boolean isEdited(){ 

    for (int i = 0; i <= EDITTEXT_IDS.length; i++ ){
        EditText edittext = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(EDITTEXT_IDS[i]);
        if(edittext.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            // the edit text is empty, so not all edit texts have had input
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    // we reached this point so all edit texts have been given input
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: WillJBD, I appreciate your help a lot. Thank you! I have been developing for some months now and have not utilized android debug.